# C++ "Invalid operands to binary expression" in cout

Tags: c++, string

New to C++ getting an odd error with cout trying to output text.  Here is the problematic area of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string courseName, courseNum;

cout << "Enter a four letter course name: ";
cin >> courseName >> endl;

cout << "Enter a three digit course number: ";
cin >> courseNum >> endl:

return 0;
}
```

The errors come up on the following lines:

```
cout << "Enter a four letter course name: ";
```

and

```
cout << "Enter a three digit course number: ";
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: `>> endl` is invalid.

Comment: : should be ; in cin>> courseNum >> endl

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cout << "Enter a four letter course name: ";
cin >> courseName;

cout << "Enter a three digit course number: ";
cin >> courseNum;
```

instead of

```
cin >> courseNum >> endl:
```

If thats not a typo then I would suspect that you may have fallen the problem of **[Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)**(Although this is my guess)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `>>endl` from `cin >> courseName >> endl;` and `cin >> courseNum >> endl;`

When users press Enter, a new line character is already there, so you do not need to explicitly add a new line.

Answer (score 0):

According to  [std::endl documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl):

> This is an output-only I/O manipulator, it may be called with an expression such as `out << std::endl` for any out of type `std::basic_ostream`.

So you should use:

```
cin >> courseName;
cout <<endl;(//make sure you really need it)
//same error on the other line
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your program as below.
endl is invalid with cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string courseName;
    string courseNum;

    cout << "Enter a four letter course name: ";
    cin >> courseName;

    cout << "Enter a three digit course number: ";
    cin >> courseNum;

    return 0;
}
```